# normalized images for not pdf files

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We are new to the whole azure AI search service. We have started our journey with use of the template provided by https://github.com/microsoft/AzureSearch_JFK_Files, which, with some rework, works good for most of our use cases.

As long as we only upload pdf files to the blob storage, the images are generated nicely and being saved in the corresponding blob storage. (and used for hOCR)
But now we also uploaded docx, pptx, etc. onto our blob storage and no normalized images are generated for these types. It seems that the indexer is not capable of creating these images for these filetypes.

Is there a specific skill that can be used to create the images of docx, pptx, etc to use in the OCR and hOCR generation?

Or do I have to create the image myself and use it on the indexer?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure AI Search there are two `imageAction` options for extracting images from documents, `generateNormalizedImages` (which is what the JFK demo uses by default) and `generateNormalizedImagePerPage`.

`generateNormalizedImages` requires that there are images embedded within the document that Azure AI Search is extracting images from. So if you have a docx or pptx that has embedded images, they will be extracted, but if they only contain text then it won't turn them into images.

`generatedNormalizedImagePerPage` will render PDF pages as images regardless of if they were embedded images before, however this only currently works on PDF. We've had a lot of requests for it to work for docx and pptx as well. For pptx it is possible and just a feature request we haven't gotten around to, but what's interesting is that it is actually impossible for docx as docx as a file type doesn't contain a concept of pages. When Word renders a docx, it displays the contents in pages, but it isn't stored that way.

Something you could try is to save your docx and pptx files as PDFs, and then use `generateNormalizedImagePerPage` to turn each page of those PDFs into images. Then OCR and the hOCR experience should work as you want.